# Using index when summing by group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, sum

I am trying to sum a variable, fPurchaseAmt, which is a float, grouped by iCompanyID, which is a BigInt. My table, Trans_smp, has 15 million rows, and about 10 other columns. In an effort to improve performance, I added an index on iCompanyID and another variable, iBrandID:

```
create index idxCompBrand on Trans_smp (iCompanyID, iBrandID);
```

No problems. I ran the following code before and after creating the index:

```
select iCompanyID, count(fPurchaseAmt) FROM Trans_smp GROUP BY iCompanyID;
```

Before creating the index, it ran in about 34 seconds, after creating the index, it ran in about 14 seconds.

I then ran the code I want:

```
select iCompanyID, sum(fPurchaseAmt) FROM Trans_smp GROUP BY iCompanyID;
```

Before creating the index, it ran in about 33 seconds, roughly the same as the count. After creating the index, it either fails or it takes a long time. The most recent time I tried it, I waited 4 hours and it didn't finish. In an effort to get it to work, I tried creating a second index, limited just to iCompanyID:

```
create index idxComp on Trans_smp (iCompanyID);
```

After creating the second index, I tried again and it didn't finish in less than 4 hours, so I pulled the plug.

After creating the second index, I tried again with the following code:

```
select iCompanyID, sum(fPurchaseAmt)
  FROM Trans_smp
  ignore index idxCompBrand
  ignore index idxComp
  GROUP BY iCompanyID
  ;
```

Once again, ran without problems in about 33 seconds.

Anyone have any ideas about what my problem is, and how to avoid it? Obviously I can just use the "ignore index" approach, but I hope to start using this and similar steps on the full set, with has 350 million rows, so I would like to be able to use indexes.

Here's the full results for "show create table":

```
create table Trans_smp (
  aTrans BigInt bigint(20) unsigned not null default '0'
  , iCustID BigInt(20) unsigned default null
  , iChainID SmallInt(5) unsigned default null
  , iDeptID SmallInt(5) unsigned default null
  , iCategoryID BigInt(20) unsigned default null
  , iCompanyID BigInt(20) default null
  , iBrandID BigInt(20) unsigned default null
  , dTransDt date default null
  , fProductSz float default null
  , cProductMeasure char(8) default null
  , iPurchaseQty MediumInt(9) default null
  , fPurchaseAmt float default null
  , key idxCompBrand (iCompanyID, iBrandID)
  , key idxComp (iCompanyID)
  )
  engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

Comment: Show full schema on table, including indexes and database engine.

Comment: In order to speed up the second query with sum(fPurchaseAmt), create an multicolumn index on these columns: iCompanyID, fPurchaseAmt.

Comment: I tried adding the multicolumn index, and it didn't fix the problem - the query stills runs for several hours (at least), while the version with the "ignore index" statement runs in ~30 seconds.